# ASP.NET Web API 2 and Ninject - Ambiguous match found

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I upgraded my project to MVC5 and Web API 2 and now receiving the following error for my Ninject filter bindings for ASP.NET Web API.  I have the package Ninject.Web.WebApi-RC installed.  Any solutions on how to fix this?

```
kernel.BindHttpFilter<ApiValidationFilter>(FilterScope.Action)
    .WhenControllerHas<ApiValidationAttribute>();

kernel.BindHttpFilter<HttpHeaderFilter>(FilterScope.Controller)
    .WhenControllerHas<HttpHeaderAttribute>()
    .WithConstructorArgumentFromControllerAttribute<HttpHeaderAttribute>("name", q => q.Name)
    .WithConstructorArgumentFromControllerAttribute<HttpHeaderAttribute>("value", q => q.Value);
```

Source Code Error:

```
public static IEnumerable<object> GetCustomAttributes(this HttpControllerDescriptor actionDescriptor, Type type)
{
    return ((IEnumerable)typeof(HttpControllerDescriptor)
        .GetMethod("GetCustomAttributes").MakeGenericMethod(type)
        .Invoke(actionDescriptor, new object[0])).Cast<object>();
}
```

Error

```
<Response>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>Ambiguous match found.</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.RuntimeType.GetMethodImpl(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConv, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers) at System.Type.GetMethod(String name) at Ninject.Web.WebApi.FilterBindingSyntax.HttpActionDescriptorExtensionMethods.GetCustomAttributes(HttpControllerDescriptor actionDescriptor, Type type) in d:\Projects\Ninject.Web.WebApi\src\Ninject.Web.WebApi\FilterBindingSyntax\HttpActionDescriptorExtensionMethods.cs:line 54 at Ninject.Web.WebApi.FilterBindingSyntax.FilterFilterBindingBuilder`1.<>c__DisplayClass9.<WhenControllerHas>b__8(HttpConfiguration controllerContext, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) in d:\Projects\Ninject.Web.WebApi\src\Ninject.Web.WebApi\FilterBindingSyntax\FilterFilterBindingBuilder.cs:line 166 at Ninject.Web.WebApi.FilterBindingSyntax.FilterFilterBindingBuilder`1.<>c__DisplayClass2.<When>b__0(IRequest ctx) in d:\Projects\Ninject.Web.WebApi\src\Ninject.Web.WebApi\FilterBindingSyntax\FilterFilterBindingBuilder.cs:line 126 at Ninject.Planning.Bindings.BindingConfiguration.Matches(IRequest request) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Bindings\BindingConfiguration.cs:line 129 at Ninject.Planning.Bindings.Binding.Matches(IRequest request) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Bindings\Binding.cs:line 237 at Ninject.KernelBase.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<SatifiesRequest>b__1b(IBinding binding) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:line 455 at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) at Ninject.KernelBase.CanResolve(IRequest request) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:line 314 at Ninject.KernelBase.Resolve(IRequest request) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:line 345 at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.GetResolutionIterator(IResolutionRoot root, Type service, Func`2 constraint, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Boolean isOptional, Boolean isUnique) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Syntax\ResolutionExtensions.cs:line 263 at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.GetAll[T](IResolutionRoot root, IParameter[] parameters) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Syntax\ResolutionExtensions.cs:line 113 at Ninject.Web.WebApi.Filter.NinjectFilterProvider.GetFilters(HttpConfiguration configuration, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) in d:\Projects\Ninject.Web.WebApi\src\Ninject.Web.WebApi\Filter\NinjectFilterProvider.cs:line 57 at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor.<InitializeFilterPipeline>b__0(IFilterProvider fp) at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__0.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ReverseIterator>d__a0`1.MoveNext() at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor.<RemoveDuplicates>d__3.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ReverseIterator>d__a0`1.MoveNext() at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor.InitializeFilterPipeline() at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() at System.Lazy`1.get_Value() at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor.GetFilterPipeline() at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor.GetFilterGrouping() at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
</StackTrace>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Web.API 2.0 the `HttpControllerDescriptor` has no two overloads for the `GetCustomAttributes` method so the `.GetMethod("GetCustomAttributes")` throws this exception.

So this is a bug in Ninject however this was fixed at 2013-10-25: [Fixed FilterInjection for WebApi2](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.WebApi/commit/d13047685373ce78b6fa983cbaa7a7e2c4071f8d).

So you have <strike>three</strike> one options:

- <strike>wait</strike> **update to the newest release** of the Ninject.Web.WebApi-RC package which contains this bugix which is currently: [Ninject.Web.WebApi 3.0.2-unstable-9018](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Web.WebApi/3.0.2-unstable-9018)
- <strike>you get the source from GitHub and built it for yourself.</strike>
- <strike>instead of the `WhenControllerHas` helper use `When` where you use the fixed `GetCustomAttributes` calling logic.</strike>

Comment: I already had the source in the project so I just updated the code and it seems to be working.

Comment: The updated code works for actions, but still erroring out for controllers.

Comment: @Omar The [bug](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.WebApi/commit/d13047685373ce78b6fa983cbaa7a7e2c4071f8d) was in the `HttpActionDescriptorExtensionMethods.GetCustomAttributes` so until the new version is not released you need to rewrite [every method](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.WebApi/search?q=GetCustomAttributes&ref=cmdform) which uses it like the `WhenControllerHas` or the `WhenActionMethodHas`

Comment: I couldn't get it to work the code you provided. Any reason you're calling `GetCustomAttribute` like that as opposed to my answer?

Comment: In your code you can call `actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes` directly, in my answer I've copied and modified the source code the from the Ninject source code repository. And I cannot tell you why Ninject call it like this. Anyway a new version of the web.api integration is out on nuget: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Web.WebApi/3.0.2-unstable-9018 so this version should fix this issue permanently.

Answer (score 1):

nemsev's answer pointed me in the right direction, but I ended up having to use the following:

```
kernel.BindHttpFilter<ApiValidationFilter>(FilterScope.Action)
    .When((controllerContext, actionDescriptor) => 
            actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<ApiValidationAttribute>().Any());
```